# Dynamically cast a control type in runtime

Tags: c#

I have an application whereby I dynamically create controls on a form from a database.
This works well, but my problem is the following:

```
    private Type activeControlType;        

    private void addControl(ContainerControl inputControl, string ControlName, string Namespace,
        string ControlDisplayText, DataRow drow, string cntrlName)
    {
        Assembly assem;
        Type myType = Type.GetType(ControlName + ", " + Namespace);
        assem = Assembly.GetAssembly(myType);

        Type controlType = assem.GetType(ControlName);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
        Control tb = (Control)obj;
        tb.Click += new EventHandler(Cntrl_Click);
        inputControl.Controls.Add(tb);
        activeControlType = controlType;
    }

    private void Cntrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string test = ((activeControlType)sender).Text;  //Problem ???
    }
```

How do I dynamically cast the sender object to a class that I can reference the property fields of it.

I have googled, and found myself trying everything I have come across..... Now I am extremely confused... and in need of some help

Thnx

JT

Comment: What's your final goal? Just to get the text of every possible control, or something more?

Comment: the.Text was just an example, at the end of the day I would like to get different properties of the control depending on what type of control it is....

Comment: so `dynamic` is the only way - be thankful for .NET 4! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only cast to a type known at compile-time. So either you need to use a known baseclass or interface you can cast to, or you need to use reflection. In C# 4 the reflection based approach is much easier than in earlier versions, since it introduces the `dynamic` keyword. I prefer the statically typed approach where possible.

In C# 4 you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dynSender=(dynamic)sender;
dynSender.Text="A";
```

Or if you know it's derived from `Control`:

```
Control controlSender=(Control)sender;
controlSender.Text="A";
```

And since you already cast to `Control` in your creation code, you know that your object is derived from `Control` in your example. And since the `Text` property is declared in `Control` this is enough to access it.

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler, you can check the type using "is":

```
if (sender is TextBox)
{
   var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
   textbox.Text = "hello";
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking with 'is' and then casting,  it's better to cast using 'as' and test for null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Visitor pattern.
For example:
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx#_self1